# Attribute similar to [ActionName] but for controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Does attribute similar to `[ActionName]` but for controller exists?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Seems like you could solve your problem with a route.

Comment: It seems I can use route for replicate `[ActionName]` too, anyway it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such attribute. You would have to write your own `IControllerFactory`. You could start by deriving from `DefaultControllerFactory`.

Comment: Or yeah, use a route. I was focused on providing a way for having a `ControllerNameAttribute`. Didn't actually think about what the OP's end goal was.